# League/Flysystem fstat() expects parameter 1 to be resource, object given

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, intervention, flysystem

I am in the process of upgrading a project from Laravel 5 to 5.1. One package that needed to be updated was `League\Flysystem`.

I am using `Intervention\Image` to resize an image and then Flysystem to save it to S3. The code below was working with 5.0 -

```
// Album ID
$id = $request->input('id');
// Filename for this photo
$filename = str_random() . ".jpg";

// Get the storage disk
$disk = Storage::disk('s3');

// Resize the photo
$image = Image::make($request->file('photo'));
$image->orientate();
$image->resize(1024, 748, function ($constraint) {
            $constraint->aspectRatio();
});
$image->encode('jpg');
// Save the photo to the disk
$disk->put("img/album/$id/$filename", $image);
```

But now I am receiving the following error: 
`fstat() expects parameter 1 to be resource, object given`, thrown in `league\flysystem\src\Util.php`, line 250.

I am using `"intervention/image": "~2.1"`, `"league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3" : "~1.0",`

Any ideas what might be causing this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You might have been lucky before some type casting on your `$image` object made a string out of it, I guess a simple change of your last line to

```
$disk->put("img/album/$id/$filename", $image->__toString());
```

will fix the problem and is safer anyway as the `put` method officially only accepts strings (and looking at the implementation of php resources as wekk).
That should keep you compatible to changes in the long run.

Comment: Now receive Command `(_toString) is not available for driver (Gd)`.

Comment: is that a writing error (_toString) or did you have only one underscore? It should be __toString() with two underscores.

Comment: Sure, so first of all `put` accepts either a string or a php resource. I guess that it worked before was because somewhere inside the flysystem code a string function or an explicit string cast happened on the input argument (so something in the lines of `(string) $image` which would do the same as doing $image->__toString()). That is a magic method that is used to convert the given object into a string whenever necessary and intervention Image implements it. _toString is not implemented and throws the error because intervention tries to execute that as Image (manipulation) command.

Comment: Got it, thanks! Was expecting this to be much harder to solve. Really appreciate the help. :)

Comment: Great I could be of help. :) Sometimes if you expect something to be hard to solve you don't see the easy solution, have the same problem sometimes :)

Answer (score 17):

The better way to do this is to type cast the encoded output:

http://image.intervention.io/api/encode

```
$image->encode('jpg');
$disk->put("img/album/$id/$filename", (string) $image);
```

Comment: I actually agree, do the typecast like suggested :)

Comment: This approach works well with Guzzle. Nice and simple.

Answer (score 0):

i got version `"intervention/image": "^2.4",`

The `__toString()` didn't work for me, the file was created corrupted...
i did `->stream()->getContents()`.